# PHP Adding spaces when I change content type to JSON

Tags: php, json

I have a very weird problem where, if I send a header to the client that the content type is "application/json", then PHP will inexplicably add spaces to the beginning of the document. If I change the document type back to normal, the spaces are gone.

To make sure that its not the browser trying to pretty-print, I tried Curl'ing the site, and the same result was achieved.

The top one is with json content type, and bottom is with default.

```
$ curl https://*****.so/api/
    {"success":false,"error":{"code":2,"message":"API access node not found"}}
$ curl https://*****.so/api/
 {"success":false,"error":{"code":2,"message":"API access node not found"}}
```

The reason I want to solve this, is because many JSON parsers will break if the first symbol you pass to them isn't `{` because they are unable to parse spaces.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is something in your PHP code that adds those spaces.

For example, your code might look like this:

```
   <?php
echo 'something';
?>
```

This code makes PHP send three spaces before executing the PHP code.

So, you need to check all code outside `<?php` and `?>` tags, and make sure there is no spaces there.

Comment: Oh wow, that was so dumb of me, one of my library files had indentation before the opening php tag. Thanks. For everyone else, just search your entire project for "    <?" and delete every space before the tags. Thanks.